# In creator it's huge, but window is small

Tags: qt

I have this problem. As you see in creator it is all huge but in window application it is normal, because in designer I had to make it big, so application look better. Why is it like this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `minimum size` of the buttons bigger in order to have them show bigger. The `sizePolicy` is also your friend when working with UI elements in Qt. By default this property is set as `preferred` which is usually a very good setting, but does not set things bigger than they must be.

Also, consider using `layouts` for more dynamic control over the UI.